# Check if a number N is sum of multiple of 3 and 5 given that N could be as big as 100,000

Tags: algorithm, optimization

How do I check if a number is sum of multiples of 3 and 5 given that the number could be **as big as 100,000** . I need an **optimized** way to break a number into two parts such that the two parts are multiple of 3 and 5 **only** and the part which is multiple of 3 is greater than the part which is multiple of 5 and if that kind of splitting is not possible then I need to reject that number .

Eg:

```
1  => cant be split so rejected ,
35 => 30 + 5 ,
65 => 60 + 5 (Though 30 + 35 could be a split but since part which is multiple of 3 has to be                greater than the part which is multiple of 5),
11 => 6+5
```

Comment: what does your best attempt look like?

Comment: 39 = 15 + 24. Why do you say it can't be split?

Comment: @interjay - 24 is not a multiple of 3 and 5 **only**. It's not even a multiple of 5.

Comment: I think every number above a certain `N` can be split that way. (and `N` will be low, like `19` which one has a `9+10` split)

Comment: @ypercube - Though the requirement that the 3 multiple be larger than the 5 multiple throws a monkeywrench in the works.

Comment: @IVlad 24 is a multiple of 3. I don't know what "only" is supposed to refer to. In the examples given, 35->30+5: 5 is not a multiple of 3. 30 is a multiple of 2, 3, and 5.

Comment: Nevermind. You should add some clarifications, your examples contradict your problem statement.

Comment: @IVlad - If each number must be a multiple of both, how do you enforce "the part which is multiple of 3 is greater than the part which is multiple of 5"?

Comment: 39 -> 15 + 24. Now what?

Comment: My bad i couldn't think of 39 as a split . 24 + 15 is correct split . but yes apart from that I think I have made the problem clear I need the split of a number N with multiple of 3 and 5 where multiple of 3 has to be bigger than the multiple of 5 . If this split is not possible then the number is rejected .

Comment: @HotLicks Indeed. But `19` is with the extra requirement. Otherwise, any number above `7` can be split into a multiple of 3 + a multiple of 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every (integer) number modulo 3 yields 0, 1 or 2.

So let's examine all cases (n > 3 must yield for obvious reasons):

1. `n % 3 == 0`. Easy: We just take `0 == 0 * 5` and `n / 3` as splitting.
2. `n % 3 == 2`. Easy again: One number will be `5` and the other `(n-5) / 3`. When subtracting 5 from n, we will create a second number `(n-5)`, which falls under the first case.
3. `n % 3 == 1`. Same as in case 2, but this time we substract `10 == 2*5`.

   A small problem is the property that the multiple of 3 has to be larger than the one of 5. For this to hold true, n has to be at least 22. ( `22 == 2 * 5 + 3 * 4`).

So all numbers smaller than 22 with the property `n % 3 == 1` have to be rejected: `4, 7, 10, 13, 16 and 19`. (As long as the factor for the multiples have to be non-negative).

Comment: Thanks a ton for the clarification . I had the idea just couldnt find the relation . My approach was to do N-5 in loop unless the (N-5)%3 == 0 . This helps magically .

Comment: You mean *"rejected: `4, 7, 10, 13, 16 and 19`"* (not 21)

Comment: I wonder why you reject 21 though. It can be written as `21+0`

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to find a way to split a number to two parts, where the first part is a multiple of `3` and the second is a multiple of `5`, with the extra requirement that the first (multiple of 3) part is greater than than the second (multiple of 5) part, then it's rather trivial:

Every number from 20 and above can be split that way.

**Proof**: For given number `N`, exactly one of the three numbers, `N`, `N-5`, `N-10` will be a multiple of 3 (consider `modulo 3` arithmetic.) So, one of these three splits satisfy the requirements:

```
N      0
N-5    5
N-10  10
```

and since `N >= 20`, the 1st part is greater (or equal) than the 2nd.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head --

Make Q = N / 3, integer division, rounding down.  Make R the remainder.

If R = 0 you're done.

If R == 2, decrement Q.

Else R must be 1, subtract 2 from Q.

Your answer is Q * 3 and N - (Q * 3).  Check that all results are positive and that the 3s multiple > 5s multiple restriction is satisfied.

(Note that this is essentially the same as Sirko's answer, but I felt it worthwhile to think it through separately, so I didn't attempt to analyze his first.)

Answer (score -2):

max divisor of 3 and 5 is 1.
so when N = 3, or N >= 5, it can be sum of multiple of 3 and 5.

Comment: So, you seem to prove that 7 **can** be written as a sum of a multiple of 3 and a multiple of 5? Can you show us how?

Answer (score -5):

Just use this code:-
Enjoy :)

```
$num = 0; // Large Number
$arr = array();
if(isset($_POST['number']) $num = $_POST['number'];
// Assuming you post the number to be checked.

$j=0;

for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++) 
{

if(($num-$i)%3==0 || ($num-$i)%5==0) { $arr[j] = $num - $i; $j++; }

 }
 //This creates an array of all possible numbers.
 $keepLooping = true;
 while($keepLooping)
 { 
  $rand = array_rand($arr,2);
  if(($rand[0] + $rand[1]) == $num) 
   {
    //Do whatever you like with them. :)
   }

    }
```

I haven't tested it though but just for your idea. Instead of the for loop to select the possibilities, you can choose some other way whichever suits you.

Comment: 1. Please explain what your answer is doing instead of just dumping a block of code. 2. This is horribly slow, and not even correct. It basically enumerates all multiples of 3 and 5 and then keeps randomly (!!!) picking two of them until it finds a solution. If there is no solution it will keep trying forever.